# from where and when can i get initiated?

Tags: shiva

im 17yo. i've a lot of bhakti towards Shiva and Devi. Im a student and i try to perform any kind of spiritual activity i can perform myself without Guru. my family is not that dharmik they have no idea of Initiation. Im a Kshatriya. becz I have not received Diksha from Guru i'm not able to experience true hindu spirituality! idk how and from where can i get diksha !! im very eager to meet my Guru.

Comment: You should try to look for Gurus in your own city ... If your city has Ramakrishna Mutt or similar well known Mutts then you can approach them too. They initiate interested and qualified people.

Comment: Ask lord Shiva I am sure he will help you out finding your Guru, Ask him to show your Guru